# Serving static files from elastic beanstalk not working

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got an angular app that is working perfectly fine from localhost, but on beanstalk it's not serving all my files. Only my index.html and styles.css is found and served, both are in one folder called public in my root.
my build file is in the path /build/build.js and it won't serve it but on local host it will.

I'm currently just serving files from my server and not using the staticfiles.config since that is completely not working.

folder structure:

```
root:  
/public : index.html ,styles.css
/src: modularized angular and htmls for routes . 
/build: build.js
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const emailController = require('./controllers/emailController');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../public')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../')));

app.post('/email', emailController);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on mfing ${port}`);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <meta name="description" content="Hydration Packs and Cooler Bags for Hiking, Outdoors, Work, Festivals, Biking and More">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles.css">
  <script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="/node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="/build/build.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Hydration Packs and Cooler bags | Absolute Zero</title>
</head>
```

Here is my server and head of my index.html. anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the script searches with this. you need to use `./`.

```
  <script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="./build/build.js"></script>
```

Comment: didn't work. when i put my build in my public folder and use ./build.js it works fine without putting ./ on my angular src's. i've also tried ../build/build.js which doesnt work.

Comment: can you take those files and put them in public folder too? or just `copy paste` them inside script tags if they're not too long? or you could upload them to a website with an extension of `.js` and put the link in `src` attribute. Three ways I have showed you, here you go! =) @JiniHendrix

Comment: the strange thing is my angular files are being served but my build file isnt

Comment: so now it's your build file? @JiniHendrix then get that file out of `public` dir and put next to angulars. :)

Comment: looks like it wont serve files out of a folder named build for some reason. ive changed it to 'buildy' and it served it fine. STRANGE STUFF.

Comment: great, hope I was some help! whenever you confront situations like these just play with the file names and dirs, also, you have more than one option as I told you.

Comment: can you set it answered @JiniHendrix